# *O(n)* "forward" Data.Vector `permute` function

Tags: haskell

The [`Data.Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) API provides an efficient [`backpermute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.7.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html#v:backpermute) function, which basically applies a index-mapping `σ`-vector to a vector `v`, i.e. `v'[j] = v[σ[j]]`.

Or expressed in list-syntax (for simplicity):

```
backpermute :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
backpermute σ v = map (v !!) σ
```

Which can have *O(n)* complexity if `!!` has *O(1)* complexity (which I assume for `Data.Vector`). Now I want the inverse "forward" `permute` operation (or alternatively a function for inverting the `σ`-vector itself), i.e. something like (again in list-syntax):

```
permute :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
permute σ = map snd . sortBy (comparing fst) . zip σ

invperm :: [Int] -> [Int]
invperm σ = permute σ [0..]
```

Alas, the code above is not *O(n)* due to `sortBy`. But since `σ` is assumed to be a permutation of a prefix of `[0..]` `permute` should be expressible as a *O(n)* algorithm with the `Data.Vector` API.

So, how can I implement an efficient *O(n)* `permute` (or alternatively an *O(n)* `invperm`) in terms of the `Data.Vector.*` APIs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Monadic initialization, perhaps?

```
invSigma :: Vector Int -> Vector Int
invSigma s = create $ 
             do v <- new n
                zipWithM_ (write v) s (enumFromN 0 n)
                return v
  where n = V.length s
```

Answer (score 6):

So `permute` is supposed to take a vector of indices and a vector of values and make a new vector so that each value is stored at the corresponding index, i.e. `v'[σ[j]] = v[j]`, the inverse of `backpermute`.

From what I can tell, there's no function in `Data.Vector` for building a new `Vector` out of index-value pairs, but there is one that updates an existing vector, namely
 [`update :: Vector a -> Vector (Int, a) -> Vector a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.7.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html#v%3aupdate). Its runtime is *O(m+n)* where *m* is the size of the vector and *n* is the number of updates.

There's also the variant [`update_ :: Vector a -> Vector Int -> Vector a -> Vector a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.7.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html#v%3aupdate_), which takes two vectors instead of a vector of pairs. Perfect. Now we just need an initial vector to "overwrite" with these values. Assuming  `σ` is a valid permutation, all the items will be updated, so any vector of the same type and length as `v` will do, so we can just reuse `v`.

```
permute :: Vector Int -> Vector a -> Vector a
permute σ v = update_ v σ v
```

Since `σ` has the same length as `v`, the runtime is *O(n)*.

A somewhat safer option is to use a vector of bottom values. That way, you will get an error if you try to read an item for which there was no index in `σ` rather than silently getting the wrong results.

```
permute σ v = update_ (replicate (length v) undefined) σ v
```

Comment: Fyi, I've benchmarked your `update_`-based version against Anthony's monadic version with criterion, and his outperformed yours by ~100% for very small vectors (10 elements), and by ~20% for much larger vectors (10^6 elements)...

Comment: @hvr: Makes sense, as I suppose it copies the original vector first and then overwrites it.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, but I'm accepting Anthony's cause his provides a slightly more direct approach to the task at hand