# Invert a permutation in linear time, using only lists

Tags: list, haskell, permutation

I want to define a function

```
invert :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

that assumes that its input is a permutation of `[0..(n-1)]`, and returns its inverse. Can one define it using only lists and tuples (without arrays) so that it runs in linear time?

This is primarily out of academic interest; in real code I might use `Array` or `STArray` or similar.

Comment: Can you explain what is an invert of a permutation list?

Comment: Tarrasch, have a look here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InversePermutation.html

Comment: I like this question, but I believe it's not possible to do it in O(n). A straightforward method requires sorting. If Haskell lists supported O(1) indexing and appending, then it would be possible.
Many operations in `Data.List` are O(n), so we're very limited in terms of efficiency.

Comment: @Kenji, I think it's possible using arrays.

Comment: dmitry, yeah, definitely. A counting/bucket sort would do it. =)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about linear time, just a beginner note.

```
λ> (\x -> map snd $ sort $ zip x [1..(length x)]) [3,8,5,10,9,4,6,1,7,2]
[8,10,1,6,3,7,9,2,5,4]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this uses a comparison sort, so it will be Ω(n log n).

Comment: By the way, you can omit the `length x`, just zip with `[1..]`.

Answer (score 2):

So, this doesn't use "only lists". But it seemed to fit so well.

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

invert :: [Int] -> [Int]
invert list = V.toList $ vec V.// assocs
  where vec = V.fromList list -- better ideas for initializing vec?
        assocs = zip (map pred list) [1..]
```

See [the Vector package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9/doc/html/Data-Vector.html), which claims that `//` is *O(n)*. Well, it says *O(n+m)*, but in this case, `n = m`.

I loaded it up into ghci and got the same answer as dmitry. :)

Comment: Just think of Vectors as really big tuples. ;)

Comment: [An alternative implementation using monadic initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6737456/98117). (Note: this uses zero-based indexing)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you cannot do this in linear time. For an implementation with an O(n) time complexity you will need to create the result list out of order, which you cannot do directly with cons-lists, I suppose.

Comment: I am inclined to believe that too. But then, the "obvious" recursive implementation of `reverse` is quadratic time, and there is an easy linear time implementation too. Consider `minout :: [Int] -> Int` which takes a list of distinct nonnegative integers, and returns the smallest nonnegative integer *not* present in the input. This too can be done in linear time, with some cleverness. So I wonder...

Comment: @prateek: I am not sure whether I got your point. Of course, `minout` has an obvious linear-time implementation; I'd even say that that does not need too much cleverness: `minout = foldr (max . succ) 0`. But how does this relate to `invert`? The difference between `reverse` and `invert` is that the former can construct its result in order, while the latter—I believe—cannot.

Comment: My (somewhat weak) point was just that things which look hard to do with lists in linear time might just be possible, so perhaps there is a clever way to `invert` which I have not thought of. I don't know how one might prove a negative result here. (By the way, the function you gave does not compute `minout` as I defined it - it computes 1 + the maximum element of the list : `minout [0,2,4]` should be `1`)

Comment: @prateek Ah, I am sorry: I misread your specification of `minout`. So, now I am curious: what does your clever linear-time implementation (using only lists and tuples) of this function look like?

Comment: It wouldn't fit in the comment box, and anyway to keep things organized, I posted it as a separate question-answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326660/haskell-find-smallest-nonnegative-integer-not-in-list-in-linear-time-using-on

Answer (score 1):

As there doesn't seem to be a positive  answer to the actual question, I'll add my cheat to the list of non-solutions:

```
invert :: [Int] -> [Int]
invert lst = take lng $ map (fromIntegral.(`mod`h)) $ iterate (`div`h)
                 $ sum $ zipWith (\k x->k*h^x) [0..] lst
  where h::Integer
        h = fromIntegral lng
        lng = length lst
```

Comment: I wonder at what point `k*h^x` becomes a significant slowdown factor.

Comment: Pretty soon, unfortunately! As I said, it's not really a solution; in fact, the exponentiation makes it much slower than _O_ ( _n_ log _n_ ), more like _O_ ( _n_ ² log _n_ ).

Comment: It would be _O_ ( _n_ ) on some hypothetic quantum computer with native arbitrary-precision exponentiation, though...

Answer (score 0):

If the permutations are represented as lists of disjoint cycles, then

```
invert :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
invert = map reverse
```

runs in linear time. 
I'm not sure if there's a linear way to convert back and forth between the different representations, though.