# Find smallest nonnegative integer not in list in linear time, using only lists

Tags: list, haskell

Consider a function `minout :: [Int] -> Int` which takes a list of distinct nonnegative integers, and returns the smallest nonnegative integer not present in the list. The behaviour of the function if the input has duplicates does not matter. Can this be implemented in linear time, using only lists (no arrays or vectors or other data structures with efficient random access)?

(This came up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8323013/1069039).)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `l` has all numbers between `0` and `(length l) - 1` inclusive, then `minout l` is `length l`, otherwise, it lies in `[0..(length l - 1)]`. So `minout l` always lies in `[0..(length l)]`, and only the elements of `l` which are in `[0..(length l - 1)]` are relevant. We can discard the remaining elements. Using this idea we can implement a linear-time divide-and-conquer solution. Unlike in merge sort, at each step of the recursion, we recurse into only *one* of two sublists each of which is at most half the size of the original (after doing some linear work). This gives a linear time complexity.

```
minout :: [Int] -> Int
minout = minoutaux 0
    where
    minoutaux :: Int -> [Int] -> Int -- \list base -> smallest integer >= base not occuring in list
    minoutaux base [] = base
    minoutaux base [x] = base + (if x==base then 1 else 0)
    minoutaux base xs = if (length smallpart == n2) then  minoutaux (base+n2) bigpart else minoutaux base smallpart
        where
        n = (length xs)
        n2 = n `div` 2
        smallpart = [x | x <- xs , base <= x , x < base + n2]
        bigpart = [x | x <- xs, base + n2 <= x, x < base + n]
```

In the above code, `minoutaux` is a function which given a "base" integer and a list with distinct entries, returns the smallest integer which is at least base and does not occur in the list. To do this, it discards the "irrelevant" elements which can be discarded, as explained earlier, and generates two lists, consisting of those numbers which lie in [`base`, `base + n2`) (called `smallpart`), and [`base + n2`, `base + n`) (called `bigpart`). Each of these lists will have length at most `n2`. If `length smallpart == n2`, then `smallpart` has all numbers in [`base`, `base + n2`), and so the answer must lie in `bigpart`, otherwise, there is a "gap" in `smallpart` itself, so the answer lies in `smallpart`.

Why does this run in linear time? First, the whole list of length N is traversed a few times, which needs some 10N operations, let's say. Then `minoutaux` is called on a smaller list, of size at most N/2. So we have (at most) 10N/2 more operations. Then 10N/4, 10N/8, and so on. Adding all these, we get a bound of 10(2N) = 20N. (the constant 10 was just used as an example)

Here we are traversing the list multiple times to compute its length, compute `smallpart`, compute `bigpart`, and so on. One could optimize that fairly easily by doing all this in a single pass. However this is still a linear time solution, and I wanted to make the code clearer, rather than optimize on constant factors.

This question and solution is not my original; I came across it in class when I learnt Haskell.

Comment: How does this run in linear time? I assume this runs in polynomial time. The whole list is traversed in `length`, `smallpart` and `bigpart` during each recursive call. The traversals in `smallpart` and `bigpart` can be linear due to laziness, but what about `length`?

Comment: I should perhaps have explained this in more detail earlier. Thanks for pointing it out, I edited the answer and added the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Richard Bird describes this exact problem in Chapter 1 of his book [Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521513383).  (That chapter just happens to be the preview available on Amazon.)