# Permutation of a list in haskell

Tags: algorithm, list, haskell, permutation

We are given two lists `xs :: [a]` and `ys :: [Int]`. For example:

```
xs = ["some", "random", "text"]
ys = [2, 3, 1]
```

We have to generate a new list `zs :: [a]`, such that `zs` is a permutation of `xs` generated using `ys`. For above example:

```
zs = ["random", "text", "some"]
```

Explanation: "random" occurs at 2nd position in `xs`, "text" occurs on the 3rd position and "some" occurs on the 1st position.

Till now, I have arrived at this solution:

```
f :: [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
f xs ys = getList (listArray (1, n) xs) ys where
  n = length xs
  getList :: Array Int a -> [Int] -> [a]
  getList a ys = [ a ! x | x <- ys]
```

Is there a better definition for `f` which will avoid use of array? I am looking for memory efficient solutions. Array is a bad choice if `xs` is say a large list of big strings. Time complexity of `f` could be relaxed to `O(n log n)`.

Comment: What's the problem with `Array`?

Comment: You could zip and sort, or construct a `Map Int a`, but either way incurs an extra *log(n)* factor.

Comment: Suppose n is large, say 10^6. I am looking for a solution which takes minimal extra memory, but still maintains O(n) complexity.

Comment: @ChrisMartin: Before doing zip and sort, I will need to invert ys http://stackoverflow.com/q/8322238/1843751

Comment: I am not convinced `Array` is less memory efficient than other solutions here, given that you have no hope of getting a really "streaming" solution.  Note that even if `xs` contains big strings, they will not be copied into the array, but just a reference to them. So the extra memory overhead isn't necessarily higher than constructing something like a zipped list, which needs to contain cons cells. (I don't think a list which is to be sorted can be fused away.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply sorting twice, back and forth, does the job:

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

f :: [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
f xs = map fst . sortBy (comparing snd) . zip xs . 
       map fst . sortBy (comparing snd) . zip ([1..] :: [Int])
```

So that

> Prelude Data.Ord Data.List> f ["some", "random", "text"] [2, 3, 1] 
>   ["random","text","some"]

(using the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322238/haskell-invert-a-permutation-in-linear-time-using-only-lists/8322498#8322498)).

Since we sort on `Int` indices the both times, you can use some integer sorting like radix sort, for an *O(n)* solution.